# Modifying css property of an element which is fixed at the top using javascript

Tags: java, javascript, html, css, selenium

I'm trying to take multiple screenshots in java selenium webdriver . Taking a site such as mashable.com  , there is a static header at the top. When I take my first screenshot  there is no problem but as I scroll down to take a screenshot, there is a header on top which blocks some content.

Now, I don't wish to have the header on top. Manually, I played around with the css of the site in chrome. I found that by identifying the id and setting the position from position from fixed to null , I get the header removed. Is it possible to have a general way to identify these headers (only on the top) and modify their css property using javascript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$('*').filter(function() {
if ($(this).css('position') === 'fixed'){
   $(this).css('position', 'relative');
}

});
```

Comment: Yeah, it's a good solution but, how to ensure it's the header on top. There might be many fixed components on the page. But, I want only the top header to be removed